# how to solve this op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework, math

I would appreciate some help solving this simple circuit which I'm trying for some time but can't seem to match with the given answer.
Aim is to find output voltage \$V_o\$

[image]

for the given input voltage -

[image]

My attempt : Since the only current flow \$i\$ is from \$V_O\$ to ground via 4k and 1k resistors, and \$V_+=V_{in}\$ $$i(mA)=V_{in}/1$$
$$\Rightarrow V_o=V_{in}+i*4=5V_{in}$$

So that when \$V_{in}\$ vary from (-5 to -2); (-2 to 2); (2 to 5)., \$V_o\$ saturates at -10; varies linearly to 10; then saturates at 10.

But the output is given as -

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your circuit doesn't have negative feedback: -

[image]

Therefore it acts as a comparator with hysteresis and hence, the output changes state when the input voltage passes the hysteresis threshold points shown below in red dots: -

[image]

The non-inverting version is also known as a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger) circuit: -

[image]

[image]

Comment: ...and it took Andy 8 minutes to answer :-) This is rad... Andy are you an employee of StackExchange? Even for an employee this response time would be stellar.

Comment: @frr I did a very simple answer when I first answered and built on it over the next 20 minutes. If it's worth answering, it's worth answering well. No, not an employee of stack exchange.